# Accessing dates in query string using Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, php-carbon

In my Laravel project, I have a dashboard that displays data on a weekly basis. Now, I need to provide a way for users to toggle between weeks, and to have the dashboard data update accordingly.

Ideally, I would use query parameters to achieve this—something like `domain.dev/dashboard?start=2017-01-02&end=2017-01-08`. Then, if a user hit a back button, they could return the week previous (e.g. `domain.dev/dashboard?start=2016-12-26&end=2017-01-02`), and so on.

Here's my current route:

```
Route::get('/dashboard/weekly', [
    'as' => 'providerDashboardIndex', 'uses' => 'DashboardController@indexWeekly'
]);
```

Here's the corresponding controller:

```
public function index()
{
    $user = Auth::user();
    $endDate = Carbon::today();
    $startDate = Carbon::today()->subDays(7);

    return view('providers.dashboard.index', compact('user', 'startDate', 'endDate') );
}
```

When a user hits the route initially, how would I add those query parameters to my URL? I understand date creation, but unsure how to pass those dates through.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, create string dates:

```
$endDate = Carbon::today()->toDateString();
$startDate = Carbon::today()->subDays(7)->toDateString();
```

If you want to use exactly `/dashboard?start=2017-01-02&end=2017-01-08` URI format, `dashboard` route should like like this:

```
Route::get('dashboard', ....
```

Then you'll be able to create a link in a view:

```
{{ url('dashboard?start=').$startDate.'&end='.$endDate }}
```

To get dates in a controller use `request()` helper:

```
public function showDashboard()
{
    $startDate = request('startDate');
    $endDate = request('endDate');
```

Comment: ?start=').$startDate.'&end='.$endDate
should be
?startDate=').$startDate.'&endDate='.$endDate for the controller to work.